# Generalised Least Square and Square Root of a Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-least-squares

Consider a generalised least square problem as follows.
$$
\mathbf y = \sigma \mathbf x + \mathbf e,
$$
where $\mathbf x, \mathbf y\in \mathbb R^n, \sigma\in(0, \infty),\mathbf e \sim \mathscr N(0, \sigma^2\Sigma)$. Note that $\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix and the coefficient and the scale parameter is the same $\sigma$ in this particular case. Next, to transfer this problem to ordinary least square, we can rewrite $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma^{0.5}\Sigma^{0.5}$ as suggested in many books. However, there seems to be more than one possible $\Sigma^{0.5}$ depending on decomposition methods used. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Square_roots_of_positive_operators). Some books suggest using Cholesky decomposition. My question are: is there a unique square root for $\Sigma$? If not, what $\Sigma^{0.5}$ should be used?  Thanks.

**Update:**
I used both decomposition mentioned in the answer below and plot the data on its original scale and transformed scales as follows. It is clear that the two look different. But the fitted line in both cases will have the same slope, i.e., coefficient estimate. So my question is whether there exists any meaningful difference between the two decomposition? It seems to me that the first one produced less influential points comparing with the second one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not able to add this as a comment, but the answer on math exchange explains it. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/350789

Comment: Thanks. It shows the unique existence of a positive definite square root. But it does not say what square root to use in generalised regression problem. Can we use both? What is the convention?

Comment: The wiki link you mentioned says
"The Cholesky factorization provides another particular example of square root, which should not be confused with the unique non-negative square root."

I think you need to use the unique square root, but I am not sure.

Comment: I do not yet understand the images and your question. But it might be helpful for it to know, that the square-root and the cholesky are simply rotations of each other.

Comment: Is the positive-definite matrix well-conditioned? If not, numerical differences in algorithms might be to blame.

Comment: @edM I did encounter problems where the covariance matrix is NO longer positive definite although they should be. So I am wondering how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Unless there is a problem with program coding, getting a non-positive-definite covariance matrix suggests that you have columns/rows that are very close to linear dependence. You might be including too many variables in your analysis so that the system is nearly over-determined. This is not my area of expertise, but I understand that some decomposition algorithms are better able to deal with ill-conditioned cases like yours seems to be. Consult the source code for functions written for R, for example, to see well-tested algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a real symmetric positive definite matrix $\Sigma$ (your covariance matrix should be real, symmetric, and positive definite), there is a unique symmetric and positive definite square root.  This is a standard theorem that can be found in many textbooks on linear algebra and matrix theory.  Note that the matrix $\Sigma$ might have other square roots that aren't symmetric and positive definite.

For your purposes, the Cholesky factorization, $\Sigma=R^{T}R$, will work just as well as the symmetric matrix square root and will typically be faster to compute.

You can use either the symmetric positive definite square root or the Cholesky factorization and you will get the same solution to the generalized regression problem.  For that matter, you could use any other matrix square root (e.g. you could use the negative of the unique symmetric positive definite square root.)

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the unique positive definite square root in $R$, please?

Comment: In the expm package of R, you'll find a function called sqrtm() that does this.

Comment: However, you're probably better off using the Cholesky factorization (chol())

Comment: Why? Is it because the latter is faster?

Comment: Yes, Chol should be considerably (say 10 times) faster.

Comment: I tried both. And I discover something rather odd. I will add some pictures in my question in about 20 minutes. Maybe you could help me understand the difference between them. Thank you!

Comment: The solution to the least squares problem is the same in either case.

Comment: That is correct. However, it is a bit puzzling to see two different transformation result in two superficially different graphs but the same regression coefficient estimate.

Comment: If your covariance matrix is badly conditioned, then this can lead to numerical problems no matter whether you use the Cholesky factor or the symmetric positive definite square root. However, there's no reason to expect that the various possible matrix square roots will produce the same transformed data- the transformation is a trick to help in solving the generalized least squares problem, not a statistically meaningful transformation.

Comment: They are meaningful in the sense that after transformation we get constant variance and so on.